# How to pass multiple parameters but show only one using uiRouter?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angular-ui-router

**Problem :** I want to pass parameter in my url e.g `/{{title}}/{{id}}` the title is **title of the content** and the id is **mongooDB ID** which is resolved(by GETting from server) before landing to the next state. I want to hide the **id** and want to show only **title** in the url .

**Expected Output:** /xyzTitle

**Current Output** /xyzTitle/dasd123123askdasdas

I want to pass the ID also , but I dont want to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a state:

```
.state('foo', {
  url: '/xyzTitle/{title}',
  params: {
    id: null
  }
})
```

Then you can either use [$state.go()](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) (moving from one state to another from a controller for example) like so:

```
$state.go('foo', { title: 'some title', id: 99 });
```

Or you can use [ui-sref](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) to move from one state to another in a template:

```
<a ui-sref="foo({ title: 'some title', id: 99 })">to foo</a>
```

Either way you don't have to have the parameters in the url. The example I gave of the state at the top has the title in the url as you requested, but also allows you to pass along the id parameter. Take a look at the ui-router documentation for [URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing), it might shed a bit more light onto this tricky issue.